# Ubuntu 18.04 Not Connecting to Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless

I recently installed 18.04 on to an external hard drive. It boots up on my Mac through rEFInd, and everything seems to be functioning properly except when connecting to the network.

I've tested this with different networks and with any of them, it asks for the WiFi password, tries to connect, and then asks for the password again.